# Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name ‘dispatcherServlet’: assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I understand that this question has been asked before multiple times but my use case is different, so I thought of posting it again.

My scenario is one spring boot service caller another one using restTemplate. I have set the restTemplate timeout for connection and read.

The callee somehow creates the following error right at the time it returns it's response back to the caller when that "return responseEntity" statement is executed:

```
DispatcherServlet (DispatcherServlet.java:1048) - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name ‘dispatcherServlet’: assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

The problem here is that the exception block around the restTemplate.postForEntity code in the caller never gets executed even though there was a read timeout occurring at the callee. I just see the above mentioned error on the console and that's it. Caller never gets any response back, neither does its exception handling logic trigger.

PS: I am testing these services using postman

Answer (score -1):

I tested the thing.The callee get exception and the return to called is Null pointer Exception with 404 response code and details

"Return Exception org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null response null"

```
@RequestMapping("rest")
public @ResponseBody String rest() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response=null;
    try {
        logger.info("Inside rest method");
        RestTemplate rest=new RestTemplate();
        setTimeout(rest,1000);
         response =rest.getForEntity("http://10.168.3.75:9009/telemune/index/call",String.class);
         logger.error("response.getBody(); " +response.getBody());
        return response.getBody();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return "Return Exception "+e +" response "+response;    
    }
}

@RequestMapping("call")
public ModelAndView call() {
    /*throw new NullPointerException();*/
    logger.info("Inside call method");
    return new ModelAndView("never");
}
```

That show if callee get exception then called doesn't get response and immediately report exception on rest controller i.e HttpClientErrorException:404 and then callee exception.

Please make me correct if i'm wrong.